# create the letter T with PHP code

Tags: php

I need to create the Letter T with PHP code:
This is what I have so far but can't seem to figure how to just have the asterisks on the top two lines in order to extend the top of the T:

```
<?php

echo "<pre>";
for ($row > 2; $row < 15; $row++) {
 for ($column = 2; $column < 12; $column++) {
 if (($row < 2 || $row < 2) || ($column < 2 || $column >= 6)) {
 echo "*";
 } 
 else echo " ";
 }
 echo "\n"; 
}
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: https://forums.digitalpoint.com/threads/question-how-to-draw-the-capital-t-using-php.251178/

Comment: "Create the letter T". What do you mean? It looks like you're trying to output asterisks in the shape of a T. Is that what you want? Why not just have a "T" and just use CSS to control the font size?

Comment: This sounds like a homework assignment to me.

Comment: the more info/detail you add the better your chance to get an answer are. Also nice formatted code is easier to read for every one

Answer (score 0):

start your for loop with `$row = 0`

```
for ($row = 0; $row < 15; $row++) {
```

you were ignoring the first 2 lines and only drawing the vertical line

Also `($row < 2 || $row < 2)` is the same as `$row < 2`

---

[@j08691 found your exact question if you want more info](https://forums.digitalpoint.com/threads/question-how-to-draw-the-capital-t-using-php.251178/)

Answer (score 0):

You have several bugs in your code.

```
for ($row > 2; $row < 15; $row++) {
 for ($column = 2; $column < 12; $column++) {
```

why do you use `$row > 2` and `$column = 2` ? Just start from zero.

```
 if (($row < 2 || $row < 2) || ($column < 2 || $column >= 6)) {
```

Why do you check if `$row < 2` is true or `$row < 2` is true if they are the same?

Here is an example:

```
echo "<pre>";
for($i=0; $i <= 10; $i++){
  for($j = 0; $j < 10; $j++){
    if($i > 2 && ($j < 3 || $j > 6)){
      echo " ";
    }else{
      echo "*";
    }
  }
  echo "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($row > 2; $row < 15; $row++) {
```

This condition is wrong, and should be:

```
for ($row = 0; $row < 15; $row++) {
```

And:

```
if (($row < 2 || $row < 2)
```

is wrong and doesn't do what you probably think it does.

The code in the thread *j08691* linked you to, contains the correct solution and you could use that:

```
<?php

echo "<pre>";
for ($row = 0; $row < 15; $row++) {
for ($column = 0; $column <10; $column++) {
if (($row < 1 || $row > 15) ||( $column == 4)) {
echo "*";
} 
else echo " ";
}
echo "\n";
} 
echo "</pre>";

?>
```

See the [live demo](http://codepad.org/trz6FRpe).

Comment: yes it is a homework assignment but I needed to see how the code is done the right way so that I can manipulate the code in the future...Thank You all for your help, greatly appreciate it!